How to drag and drop multi selected items?
I'm trying to select several elements in a list and drop them anywhere in this list. It’s easy to do one element at a time, but I couldn’t manage to select several and drop them Gif_1.
But if the List section is displayed twice, then dragging selected elements from the List to the List will be displayed with a plus sign (which means you can already drop them there) Gif_2.
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import Foundation

struct Item: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

@available(iOS 16, macOS 13, *)
extension Item: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(importedContentType: .plainText) { data in
            let string = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            return Item(name: string)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = [
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth",
        "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth"
    ].map { Item(id: UUID(), name: $0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                VStack {
                    VStack{
                        Text(item.name)
                        Text (item.id.uuidString)
                          .font(.system(size: 10))
                    }
                    .draggable(item)
                }
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
            .onInsert(of: [.plainText]) { index, providers in
                for provider in providers {
                    provider.loadObject(ofClass: NSString.self) { (nsString, error) in
                        guard let string = nsString as! String? else {
                            print(#line, "Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                            return
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let newItem = self.decodeItem(from: string)
                            self.items.insert(newItem!, at: index)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Draggable List")
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }

    func decodeItem(from jsonString: String) -> Item? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
            return try? decoder.decode(Item.self, from: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}

